# How to save space in horizontal radio button group?

Tags: uwp-xaml

Not a UI-person normally, but somehow I ended up responsible for this app :-).

I have a user control that is a radio button group inside a grid.  I'm trying to dictate that each radio button be ONLY as wide as it has to be to show the text.  Seems so trivial, but even if I hardcode a width I don't seem to be able to affect it.  Regardless I get 3 options evenly spaced apart.

```
    <Grid>
    <ItemsControl x:Name="DynamicRadioButtonItemsControl" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Options, Mode=OneWay}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel x:Name="RadioButtonStackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <RadioButton GroupName="{Binding GroupId, ElementName=InspectionItemRadioButtons}"  Content="{Binding Display}" Width="Auto"  Tag="{Binding Value}"  Checked="RadioButton_Checked"  Loading="RadioButton_Loading" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the [MinWidth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.minwidth) property, like this:

```
<RadioButton GroupName="{Binding GroupId, ElementName=InspectionItemRadioButtons}" 
    MinWidth="20" Content="{Binding Display}" Width="Auto"  Tag="{Binding Value}"  
    Checked="RadioButton_Checked" Loading="RadioButton_Loading" />
```